# Convert ArrayList to String Array

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I want to write list modal text for numberpicker. setDisplayValues is just taking String[]  how can I do it

```
public String getSure_ad_tr() {
    return sure_ad_tr;
}

public void setSure_ad_tr(String sure_ad_tr) {
    this.sure_ad_tr = sure_ad_tr;
}

public String getSure_ad_ar() {
    return sure_ad_ar;
}

public void setSure_ad_ar(String sure_ad_ar) {
    this.sure_ad_ar = sure_ad_ar;
}
```

AnasayfaFragment.xml

```
String[] sureler = new String[]{"Fatiha", "Bakara", "Ali İmran", "Nisa"};



            NPsureler.setMaxValue(sureler.length - 1);
            //implement array string to number picker
            NPsureler.setDisplayedValues(sureler);
            NPsureler.setMinValue(1);

            NPayetler.setMaxValue(7);
            NPayetler.setMinValue(1);
```

I want to write not a String[] sureler, list.get(i).getSure_ad_tr() on the setDisplayValues

how can I do it

Comment: Just Loop through the ArrayList and add add String items (sure_ad_tr) inside an Array .

Comment: You can use as following,
`String [] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`
`toArray()` method will help you convert an ArrayList to an Object Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `List.toArray()`:

```
String[] stringArr = new String[myList.size()];
stringArr = myList.toArray(stringArr);
```

Or more simple put this together in one line:

```
String[] array = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
```

Just some info of why I pass a new `String[]` to `list.toArray()`:
There are two methods, one returns `<T[]>` and one `Object[]`. Since there is no information at runtime what `T` actually is, I pass a new String array to the method so it can 'determine' the correct type.

See the Javadoc for more inforation about `List.toArray()`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html